# Suggested Opensource CMS for managing files by metadata?

Tags: pdf, open-source, content-management-system, mp3, metadata

I've been wanting to create a resources database for an organisation storing predominantly audio files (lectures) and PDFS. I'm pretty familiar with Wordpress, however I'm looking for another CMS which is more suited to what I want straight out of the box. Can anyone suggest a simple CMS which will allow files to be uploaded and managed by the metadata, rather than folder hierarchy?

Comment: any progress w/ this? I'm very interested as I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 2):

If your main goal is to create a resources database, you might be better off using a Digital Assets Management system than a traditional CMS. I found ResourceSpace (http://www.resourcespace.org/) and Razuna (http://www.razuna.org/) very useful for similar projects.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [Typo3](http://typo3.org/) combined with its [DAM](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/dam/current/) (for digital asset management) extension. I've been using it for quite a while now, and it does its job pretty good. And it'd be combined with the CMS features of Typo3, while not being very simple, sure are way more powerful than Wordpress. Also there are quite a lot of [extensions for DAM](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/?tx_terfe_pi1%5Bview%5D=search&no_cache=1&tx_terfe_pi1%5Bsword%5D=dam) itself, such as galleries and the like.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/).  It is an enterprise grade content management solution for sharing files in company.  It is quite an impressive system, and has paid support if you need it.  I've seen many very large companies implement it over other paid solutions (like EMC Documentum's eRoom).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at OpenACS file storage package.